# Set name of attributes of reactive form on HTML - Angular

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a reative form like this:

```
  profileForm = this.fb.group({
    firstName: ['', Validators.required],
    aliases: this.fb.array([
      this.fb.control('')
    ])
  });
```

How can I display firstName?

My HTML:

```
  <span>profileForm.controls.firstName</span>
```

This will display profileForm.controls.firstName. How can I can do this?

Comment: You mentioned errors in a comment. Please [edit] your question with the error. Possibly relevant... https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6099

Comment: Which error? This is a generic way on how I pretend to display, not a fesable implementation

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 <span>profileForm.get('firstName').value</span>
```

Comment: can you explain  more ?

Comment: I want to have errors when for example firstName is change on reactive form